# Limit addends to a specific value for cell with addition?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am trying to limit each addend to a constant value when adding them in a cell.

For example the cell will have

```
=32+35+8+45+40
```

However I want to remove user error and limit each addend to be `<=40`

Edit: The cell can have a (basically) unlimited number of addends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=MIN(32, 40) + MIN(35,40) + MIN(8, 40) + MIN(45,40) + MIN(40,40)`

this solves your issue

Comment: sorry I forgot to include that the cell can have basically infinite amount of addends

Comment: umm and the cell is manually filled with data, like you just write `+30`, then later `+50` or what? or you're grabbing those values from other columns using sum function?

Comment: The cell is manually filled with the data. The point is to try to remove the possibility of a human entering more than 40

Comment: if every user manually adds `his` part of this formula - like you have `=15+20` and after user enters it it looks like `=15+20+30` then there is no way to validate this, he can either type `+41` or `+213123` or delete whole formula, the only way is to tell users to enter their inputs in single column and then sum whole column and normalize each value to be `<=40`

Comment: yea thats what I figured. Thank everyone for the responses. Unless someone knows some other way around it

Comment: @pnuts yeah, there is way - creating monitoring service/bot basing on events on document save, so whenever someone edits excel file you parse the cell and check if each x in formula `=x1+x2+x3+x4+x5` is `<=40` and is valid input but it's overkill, so I guess there's no solution without some kind of external software or wild macros, if they even work on google docs